How to auto format HTML (.cshtml) documents on save (VS2022)
I rely on clean-up profile with the "run on save" checked to ensure my code is formatted on save:
'Format code' and 'sort using' on save in Visual Studio 2022
While that feature works well for code files (.cs...) it seems it was not intended to support .cshtml files (notice when the current opened document is a .cshtml, there is no cleanup icon in the status bar next the zoom option).
I can do it manually through: "Edit > Advanced > Format Document" (CTRL+E, D), also I am aware that there is an option called "Format HTML on paste", but I am looking to automatically trigger the formatting upon save.
I have done some research here, unfortunately I cannot find an up-to-date working solution (or specific stable extension) for VS2022.
PS: I am not interested to install a large or/and paid extension (like Resharper) just to use this one specific feature.
PS2: I have checked Resharper to see what it offers for this and it seems they have currently an issue with cshtml files, the syntax is not highlighted at all, same as opening a text file.

My philosophy is that you should format before saving (I have the toolbar always opened). Tha way you can actually catch some errors too.

@PoulBak i am open to that also, how would you trigger auto format on the fly? could you provide a scenario how this philosophy helps to catch errors ? what kind of error ?

It does not happen automaticslly, I just click the 'Format' button a lot. Well html is also formatted and if you forget an end tag or something, the wrong formatting sticks in the eyes.

i understand it is formatted while typing, but it could happen because of some wrong moves (potentially accumulated) not necessarily missing a closing tag that makes html unformatted but still valid, so the on save format is an extra step to guarantee the formatting without doing it manually thinking of it like an auto save

After searching some related documents on the Internet, it seems that auto format HTML documents on save via Code Cleanup is not supported at present.
But i suggest you could submit a feature request at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
